# SSL Routines error when connecting to local DB

Tags: node.js, ssl, sequelize.js

So I have this piece of code that is responsible for checking if a connection is valid:

```
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(req.body.database, req.body.user, req.body.password, {
        host: req.body.host,
        dialect: 'mssql',
        port: req.body.port,
        dialectOptions: {
            options: {
                encrypt: true,
            }
        }
      });
      sequelize.authenticate().then((err) => {
        res.send('Connected');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message)
        res.send(err.message);
      });
```

This worked perfectly when I was connecting to a local DB on my network. However, when I was trying to connect to a DB through a VPN (simulating a local network) I got the following error:

> Failed to connect to 10.1.90.20:1433 - 4C300000:error:0A000102:SSL
> routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported
> protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1983:

I read somewhere that adding

```
 cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
                    minVersion: 'TLSv1'
                }
```

in the options will resolve this but it just gave me a new error:

> Failed to connect to 10.1.90.20:1433 - 70290000:error:0A0C0103:SSL
> routines:tls_process_key_exchange:internal
> error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_clnt.c:2255:

Any idea how to fix this?
Keep in mind that both Databases are local however one of them is on a remote network accessible through SSL VPN.

Comment: How you solved that issue?

Comment: @Mendes this is long ago so can't really remember how I fixed it but this is how it is currently working:   
`const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, username, password, {
      host: host,
      dialect: 'mssql',
      dialectOptions: {
          options: {
              encrypt: false,
          }
      }
    });`